# how to upgrade my Debian package with minor changes

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, deb, patch

I created a .deb which installs some features and copies some library to /usr/lib/ location.  Now that if I have changed  one of the .so file in the package and want to update the same to Debian package, what could be the scenario.

Simply how can i update files after installing the package. In windows the same is achieved by .MSP files to corresponding .MSI . How can I do the same in ubuntu?

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First `cd` to the directory where your deb file is:

```
cd ~/lab
```

Then extract your deb file there:

```
dpkg-deb --raw-extract my.deb .
```

It will create some directories like:

```
DEBIAN  etc  usr
```

Apply your minor update whatever it's a new file removal or etc to the specific files you want.

Then recreate the package simply with:

```
dpkg-deb -b new.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can repackage with updates to the files your package supplied, however, you need to change the version manually.

I'd use `dpkg-repack`. It is a wonderful tool to repack installed debian package.

You can use this command to generate the build directory of all files for this package under the current directory using this command

```
sudo dpkg-repack --generate your-package-name-here
```

Now, after it gathers the files of the package in a folder name with format `your-package-name-some-random-number`, you can then change the package version in the geneated control file there.

You're you're done, use `dpkg-deb` to rebuild

```
dpkg-deb --build generate-folder-for-package
```

If you don't mind have the package same version, just do plain `dpkg-repack`

```
sudo dpkg-repack <your-package-name>
```